# How to comment out lines of code in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, etl

is it possible to comment out some lines of code in SSIS `Execute SQL Task`? For instance, the package has been run the 1st time and can be re-run multiple times.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[A]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[B]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[DimY]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[DimZ]
```

I want to comment out `DimY` and `DimZ`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just comment it out like you would in SQL

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[A]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[B]
--TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[DimY]
--TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[DimZ]
```

Comment: Brad, just to clarify. I know in T-SQL I can comment out with  "--" and "/**/", is this applicable in SSIS?

Comment: Yes, in an SSIS SQL Script task it is the same thing as if you were typing in SQL Management Studio.  If you comment i tout like above, it will not run it in the SSIS SQL Script task

Answer (score 0):

If you need to comment some lines of the code, it is a T-SQL code so you can use `--` and `/**/` to achieve that. But i think that in some cases it is better to disable the task by right click on it and selecting disable option. So it is easier to enable it again.